# Original array still changes after editing a sliced copy

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to save a copy of the original coordinates of the vertices of a `Geometry` object. I tried to copy the object the way I found lots of answers for here on stackoverflow.

```js
// create a Geometry object from a BufferGeometry
cityGeometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( child.geometry );

// properly copy the cityGeometry.vertices array
var originalPositions = cityGeometry.vertices.slice(0);

// change an element of the copy
originalPositions[0].z = 1000;
console.log(originalPositions[0]);
console.log(cityGeometry.vertices[0]);

// now change the original object
cityGeometry.vertices[0].z = 123;
console.log(originalPositions[0]);
console.log(cityGeometry.vertices[0]);
```

However, if I do this, both objects always change at the same time. The console output reads:

```html
Vector3 {x: 0.8206260204315186, y: -0.4336470067501068, z: 1000}
Vector3 {x: 0.8206260204315186, y: -0.4336470067501068, z: 1000}
Vector3 {x: 0.8206260204315186, y: -0.4336470067501068, z: 123}
Vector3 {x: 0.8206260204315186, y: -0.4336470067501068, z: 123}
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can should use:

```
originalPositions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( cityGeometry.vertices ));
```

as array.slice() does only a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Array#slice` only returns a shallow copy of an array -- thus, while the array references are themselves different, the vector objects within are actually the same. Since these Vector3 references are shared, modifying any vector via the copied array will mean those changes are reflected in the original array, giving the appearance that the array was never copied at all.

You can create a deep copy of your `vertices` array using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Vector3#clone`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3):

```
var originalPositions = cityGeometry.vertices.map(function (v) { return v.clone() })
```

---

### Full Code:

```js
// create a Geometry object from a BufferGeometry
cityGeometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( child.geometry );

// properly copy the cityGeometry.vertices array
var originalPositions = cityGeometry.vertices.map(function (v) { return v.clone() });

// change an element of the copy
originalPositions[0].z = 1000;
console.log(originalPositions[0]);
console.log(cityGeometry.vertices[0]);

// now change the original object
cityGeometry.vertices[0].z = 123;
console.log(originalPositions[0]);
console.log(cityGeometry.vertices[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/84/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cityGeometry.vertices` is an object array, every item in this array is a quote to an object. So, if use slice to copy the array, every item in the new array also a quote to an object.

```
var arr1 = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
var arr2 = arr1.slice();

//arr2[0] == arr1[0] === obj1;
```

They both point to the same object, so if modify arr1[0].xxx, obj1.xxx will change. the solution is use deep copy , or [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone) when object is not deep.

```
var arr1 = [{x:1}, {y:2}, {z:3}];
var arr2 = [];
arr1.forEach(function(item) {
    arr2.push(Object.assign({},item))
});
arr2[0].x = 3;
console.log(arr1[0].x, arr2[0].x);
```